# How do I Create a Chromium Distribution Package for Windows?

Tags: chromium

I really need some help on what I thought was a simple question: How do I Create a Chromium Distribution Package for Windows?

This documentation is exceptional:
Checking out and Building Chromium for Windows
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

Now that I have a build, how do I distribute it to others?

I guess I could zip up the entire "chromium/src/out/default" but that directory is 51.6 GB !!!

Is there any documentation on what is needed in a Chromium distribution package for Windows or a simple script that automates the process?  I was certain this would be an "easy find" on Googe or Stack Overflow, but not so far.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by Rob Rich at https://chromium.woolyss.com/

---

try building this target:

autoninja -C out\Default mini_installer.exe

That builds an Windows installer executable and a compressed 7z file in the output directory.

The installer is silent, so click it and wait a few seconds to maybe a minute on slower systems for the install to complete.

Alternatively, the 7z archive can be uncompressed and run from whatever directory if desired.

---

It would be good to add this information to the Chromium documentation (I have notified the Chromium DEV group).

If you Google on the phrase "autoninja -C out\Default mini_installer.exe" you literally get zero results.

There is a similar question on Stack Overflow with a similar response.  I am going to keep this question posted in hopes that it will be picked up by the Google machine.